# How to upload image instantly via FilePond

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, filepond

I want to make a program that takes a number of photos from the user. And every photo will be uploaded to the server as soon as it is selected. How can I do this?

```
<script>
    FilePond.registerPlugin(
      FilePondPluginImagePreview
    );

    $('.fileUpload').filepond({
        allowDrop: true,
        allowBrowse: true,
        allowMultiple: true,
        allowReplace: true,
        allowRevert: true,
        allowRemove: true,
        allowProcess: true,
        maxFiles: 15,
        maxParallelUploads: 1,
        itemInsertLocation: 'before',
        dropOnElement: true,
        dropValidation: true,
        instantUpload: true,
        server: {
            url: './',
            timeout: 0,
            process: {
                url: 'api/UploadPictures/Upload',
                method: 'POST',
            },
            revert: null,
            restore: null,
            load: null,
            fetch: null,
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as below:

in View:

```
<form id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input class="filepond" id="FileUpload_FormFile" type="file" name="FileUpload.PICs" multiple />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        pond = FilePond.create(
            document.querySelector('.filepond'), {
            allowMultiple: true,
            .....//othersettings
        });
    });

    $("#uploadform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formdata = new FormData(this);
        // append FilePond files into the form data
        pondFiles = pond.getFiles();
        for (var i = 0; i < pondFiles.length; i++)
        {
            formdata.append('PICs', pondFiles[i].file);
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Upload",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            method: "post"
        });
    })
</script>
```

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Upload(IFormFileCollection PICs)
        {
            ......
        }
```

Result:

[image]